# PHP DOM getElementbyID and append it?

Tags: php, domdocument

For my website i want to remove and add content if sessionname is set. 
For the remove i use this code:

```
$this->removeContent = $xpath->query('//html:a[@class="btn btnLogin"]')->item(0);
$this->removeContent->parentNode->removeChild($this->removeContent);
```

That works well. 
Now is my question hoq can i add content ?

i tried to get it by ID name and append it but i don't know how.

```
$btnLogout = $dom->getElementById('btnLogout');
$this->add_content = $xpath->query('//html:div[@class="head"]')->item(0);
$this->add_content->appendChild($dom->importNode($btnLogout, true));
```

Error: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMDocument::importNode() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given, called in /var/www/ProjectX/src/Controllers/FrontPageController.php on line 46 and defined in /var/www/ProjectX/src/Renderers/FrontPageRenderer.php on line 43

Whole PHP code for this file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Lukas
 * Date: 20.05.2016
 * Time: 23:41
 */

namespace ProjectX\Renderers {

    use DOMDocument;
    use DOMXPath;

    class FrontPageRenderer
    {
        /**
         * @var
         *
         */
        private $add_content;

        private $removeContent;

        //Rendert die Frontpage mit hilfe von DOMDocument
        public function renderFrontpage($template, $content)
        {
            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

            $xpath->registerNamespace('html', "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

            $dom->appendChild($dom->importNode($template->documentElement, true));
            //Added den Content der Seite in der Class main. 
            $this->add_content = $xpath->query('//html:div[@class="main"]')->item(0);
            $this->add_content->appendChild($dom->importNode($content->documentElement, true));
            //Remove Content
            $this->removeContent = $xpath->query('//html:a[@class="btn btnLogout"]')->item(0);
            $this->removeContent->parentNode->removeChild($this->removeContent);

            if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
                $btnLogout = $dom->getElementById('btnLogout');
                $this->add_content = $xpath->query('//html:div[@class="head"]')->item(0);
                $this->add_content->appendChild($dom->importNode($btnLogout, true));

                $this->removeContent = $xpath->query('//html:a[@class="btn btnLogin"]')->item(0);
                $this->removeContent->parentNode->removeChild($this->removeContent);
                $this->removeContent = $xpath->query('//html:a[@class="btn btnRegister"]')->item(0);
                $this->removeContent->parentNode->removeChild($this->removeContent);
            }
            return $dom->saveXML();
        }

    }
}
```

How can i add the content?

Comment: The error means that there was no element with ID `btnLogout`, so `$btnLogout` is `NULL`.

Comment: Are you sure `btnLogout` is an ID, not a class? A few lines before that, you removed `class="btn btnLogout"`. So why do you expect to be able to find it now?

Comment: Yes im sure thats the id...   if i remove it earlyer. Do i cant use it again ?  I want to add it if session name is set and remove it if not...

Comment: You should use `if/else` so that you only remove it when the session name isn't set.

Comment: I don't really like if else... Could i use switch case ? Like.. switch ($_SESSION['name']) { case isset($_SESSION['name']): remove;     sry for code im at the handy...     i tried this but something doesent work... could i not use switch case with session?

Comment: You can use `switch(isset($_SESSION['name'])) { case true: ... case false: ... }`

Comment: `if/else` is one of the most basic programming constructs. Get used to it.

Comment: Ohh nice thank you !     Do you know what is performanter ?

Comment: No, I've never heard of performanter. What is it?